# How to get access to third party lambdas on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

My application needs to call third party lambdas. The third party developer can sign in to my portal and add their lambda.

My question is what do they have to give me in order to allow my service to use it? What is the easiest way for them to allow only my service to use it?

Comment: Where do the Lambda functions reside (your account or theirs)? How will the Lambda functions be invoked (direct invocation through SDK, or S3 events, or something else)?

Comment: I want to directly invoke their lambda which resides in their account

Comment: As with typical cross-account access in AWS, they should create a cross-account IAM role that permits the relevant Lambda invocation and permits your account to assume that role.

Comment: Ok so from what I understand I need to give third parties my account id in order for them to create a role that I can assume? So I presume they can give me an Arn for the role, right? If so, is it then possible for me to switch to that role programmatically?

Comment: It seems like I can temporarily assume a role with STS. Is that the correct approach? Will that temporarily remove my current privileges? i.e. must I be careful with asynchronous operations?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Share your account ID with them, agree an external ID, and use STS to assume the IAM role arn that they share with you. That gives you credentials (access key, secret key, and security token).

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well-supported in AWS and is called "cross-account access".

The third-party should create a cross-account IAM role that permits the relevant Lambda invocation and permits your account to assume that role.

Share your account ID with them, agree an external ID, and they will share an IAM role ARN with you. Then you can use STS to assume the IAM role ARN that they shared with you. That gives you credentials (access key, secret key, and security token) to invoke their Lambda functions.